# Why function to_excel of Pandas lowercases the formulas string?

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

Thank you for helping me.

I'm trying to write an excel from a `pandas.DataFrame` using function `.to_excel()`.

It's ok, but the issues is that something happens to the formulas I have in the dataframe. Here's my code:

```
for indx in range(len(currency)):
    if currency[indx] in list_currencies:
        
        row = str(list_currencies.index(currency[indx]) + 2)
        
        c_2019 = '=%s*$Currency.%s%s'%(str(gt_2019_mzero[indx]), index_excel['2019'], row)
        c_2020 = '=%s*$Currency.%s%s'%(str(gt_2020_mzero[indx]), index_excel['2020'], row)
        c_2021 = '=%s*$Currency.%s%s'%(str(gt_2021_mzero[indx]), index_excel['2021'], row)
        c_2022 = '=%s*$Currency.%s%s'%(str(gt_2022_mzero[indx]), index_excel['2022'], row)
        c_2023 = '=%s*$Currency.%s%s'%(str(gt_2023_mzero[indx]), index_excel['2023'], row)

        gt_2019_toconvert.append(c_2019)
        gt_2020_toconvert.append(c_2020)
        gt_2021_toconvert.append(c_2021)
        gt_2022_toconvert.append(c_2022)
        gt_2023_toconvert.append(c_2023)
...
    dataframe_impacts.insert(32, 'inde_2019 >= 0 €', gt_2019_toconvert)
    dataframe_impacts.insert(33, 'inde_2020 >= 0 €', gt_2020_toconvert)
    dataframe_impacts.insert(34, 'inde_2021 >= 0 €', gt_2021_toconvert)
    dataframe_impacts.insert(35, 'inde_2022 >= 0 €', gt_2022_toconvert)
    dataframe_impacts.insert(36, 'inde_2023 >= 0 €', gt_2023_toconvert)
```

Then, in the view:

```
            # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
            options = {}
            options['strings_to_formulas'] = True
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl', options=options)
            
            # Write on excel:
            impacts.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Impacts', index=False)
            currencies_table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Currency', index=True)
```

So, for example `c_2019` should be --> `c_2019 = "=500*$Currency.C3"` (i.e. `value*%SHEET_NAME.CELL_COORDINATES`)

But what I actually get inside the excel file in the cell is `"=500*&currency.c3"`, all letters in lowercase making the formulas does not working at all.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

**I'm using: Python 3.7.8; pandas==0.25.1**

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you already try write_formula()? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html

Comment: You mean using xlsxwriter? Actually no, I could give a try

Comment: Same issue using write_formula()

Comment: Does anything changes, if you use string formatting? c_2019 = f'={str(gt_2019_mzero[indx])}*$Currency.{str(index_excel['2019']) + str(row)}' ?